# Lift application performance degrade

Tags: performance, scala, embedded-jetty, lift

I am using lift framework with embedded jetty. My application is running pretty fast if I am it in development. As soon as I make a assembly of it using SBT, the performance degrades upto  20-30 times. The request which was taking 400ms, starts taking 10sec. Does lift has something to do with assembly?

Please give me some pointers to solve this problem.

Comment: As I was working on the issue, I found out that if I run my jar file with development mode, it's performance is very slow. When I run my jar with production mode, it was running pretty fast. I am little surprise here by the fact that if I am running my application without packing in a jar, it is give same performance as it's running in a jar in production mode. Could somebody help me to understand this?

Thanks,
Puneet

Comment: if you don't get an answer here, you may want to try the mailing list at http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb .

Answer (score 0):

Could you ensure that .jar files does not contain any test resources or configuration which can slowdown application in runtime (as example configs which turning on debug/trace priority in logger or minimize size of DB connection pool).
Also please check that start scripts for application set enough limits for heap and permgen memory size.
Following JVM options are suitable for most small and mid- sized Lift web apps:

```
-server -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+TieredCompilation
```

P.S. Try to find hotspots with some profiler, and then find cause of them...